# TabBar is not showing [More…] icon while loading tabItems dynamically from view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

Here i am adding tab items dynamically but its showing only 4 items ( More... tab item is missing). I have gone through a lot of articles and stackOverFlow posts but failed to find any appropriate solution. Here is my code so far...

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    loadDynamicItems()
}

func loadDynamicItems()  {

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    var controllerArray = [UIViewController]()

    for i in 1...8 {
        let controller = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newsCollection") as! NewsVC
        let tabIcon = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .addressBook,
                                              textColor: UIColor.black,
                                              size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))

        controller.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "item \(i)", image: tabIcon, tag: i)
        controllerArray.append(controller)
    }

    self.setViewControllers(controllerArray, animated: true)
}
```

But result seems like this [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KtQ3.png) 

why Its showing only 4 items!

It should load a [More...] button as fifth child from where i can access the rest of the items. 
But why its not there !?

Comment: I think you have to use UITabController and NOT UIViewController. Look this tutorial: http://geekyviney.blogspot.com.es/2015/02/programmatically-designing.html

Comment: Why does you `for` loop, loop through 8 items when you only need 5 tab bar items?

Comment: where does call this method ?

Comment: try this in appdelegate : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15383967/3901620

Answer (score 0):

When using a Storyboard, in order to add a TabBarController to your application you need to drag and drop a UITabBarViewController instead of a plain UIViewController. Otherwise some properties are not correctly derived (like the TabBar - please see my screenshot).

Just make sure you delete the automatically created TabBar items!

[image: UITabBarViewController from Storyboard]